# Format query result as JSON in Athena

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena

In Athena, I have some data in formatted as a rather complicated struct with various nested arrays and structs:

```
struct<a:struct<b:string, c:int, d:array< ... >>>
```

I want to format my query result as a JSON string:

```
{"a": {"b": "cow", "c": 5, "d": [ ... ]}}
```

However if I cast the data to JSON, `CAST(x AS JSON)`, I just get the associated values:

```
[["cow", 5, [ ... ]]]
```

How do I get the desired format without constructing the JSON object by hand? The underlying data in the S3 bucket is JSON; is there a better way to format the table in Athena?

Comment: If the s3 bucket has the data as JSON, why did you change it to a struct in Athena, especially if you need it back as a JSON? Store the data as JSON in your Athena table so that you can retrieve later in the same format.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not create the table.  But I suspect, from what you say here, that the best solution would be to create a new table using the JSON data type.

Comment: Yes, seems like it would save you a lot of headache :)

Comment: @Ema how do you "store the data as JSON" in the Athena table? My original data is JSON and when I run the crawler I get columns, and those which are themselves JSON (i.e. nested) get converted to structs automatically. As far as I can see, Glue Catalog doesn't have a "JSON" column type.